# Why does NSFetchRequest not initialise?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm create an NSFetchRequest, and it fails to initialise (returns <uninitialized> in the debugger) when created as below.

```
let request: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = EntityName.fetchRequest()
```

However, it works perfectly when created like this:

```
let request: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "EntityName")
```

Can anyone tell me why it would work the bottom way but not the top? The top way functions perfectly in the other three classes that use it.

Comment: let request: NSFetchRequest<YourClass> = YourClass.fetchRequest... This shuld solve it

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but due to the structure of the code, I can't use specific cases for the NSFetchRequest because my NSFetchedResultsController is an inherited property from a more general class.

Comment: I have now switched completely to using the bottom method, as I've made the structure even more general, but I still would like to know why the top method worked on every other class that I used it on, and they were pretty much exact copies (the only difference was that class field, and some different code in `prepare(for: segue)`).

Answer (score 1):

I've been having the same problem with calling `NSManagedObject.fetchRequest()` on the tests target, but I was able to fix it by calling it inside a block on managed object context's `perform(_:)` method, like so:

```
context.perform {
    let request = EntityType.fetchRequest()
    (...)
}
```